# Why are these lines not the same?

Tags: jquery

So I am making a website using custom tabs and i;m curious why these lines are not equal.

relevant html:

```
<div class="bot_section clear">
      <div class="tab-panels">
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li rel="panel1" class="active">Routebeschrijving</li>
          <li rel="panel2">Contact</li>
        </ul>
```

and this is the working code:

```
$(".tab-panels .tabs li").on('click', function() {
    $(".tab-panels .tabs li.active").removeClass('active');
```

and this is the reworked code, which refers to the same (but not quite it seems):

```
    $activeTab = $(".tabs").find("li.active");

    $tab.on('click', function() {
        $activeTab.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
```

In the first(unclean) code, it removes the active class on both li's, however the cleaner code only removes the active class on panel (panel2 always remains active).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$activeTab = $(".tabs").find("li.active");
```

is only searched for once on your page, so it will only work the first time you click. This is because you don't search for the `active` li every time you click. (it's not in the click event's body as in the other sample code you provided)

So the first code is:

1. search for the active li and save it
2. click -> remove the active class from the saved element
3. click -> remove the active class from the saved element (which doesn't have the active class anymore)

The second code is

1. click -> search for the element with the active class remove the active class from this element
2. click -> search for the element with the active class remove the active class from this (probably new) element

Comment: Yes you are correct, when I place the code inside the click function it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, you evaluate `$("[...] li.active")` inside the `click` handler, meaning that you query for the currently active `li` every time a `li` is clicked.

In the second script, you evaluate `$("[...] li.active")` **just once** and store the result in `$activeTab`. After you've clicked `panel2`, `$activeTab` will still hold `panel1` while it no longer has the `active` class.

A fix for the second script would be to *update* the `$activeTab` variable when changing the classes:

```
$activeTab = $(".tabs").find("li.active"); // <- Initial value
$tab.on('click', function() {
    $activeTab.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $activeTab = $(this); // <- Update value
});
```

(If you're feeling adventurous, you can combine those two lines into just `$activeTab = $(this).addClass('active')`. However, that might break if you chain more stuff after the `addClass`...)